# Node.js with Webstorm -

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, webstorm

I've followed [this example](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/06/mean-stack-walkthrough-and-tips/) to try and add a record to MongoDB database.

When trying to run `./server/server.js` I get the following message (at 2:22 in video):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" server.js
CreateProcess failed with error 193 (no message available)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The `node.exe` path is right but don't know why I'm getting this error and can't find information on debugging it.

Comment: It looks from that message as though Webstorm is trying to run `npm` (node package manager, which is a script) on server.js, rather than the node executable `node.exe`.

Comment: Yep. best advice I can give is run a virtual machine with a linux installation. Most things run happy that way. It's what people "expect" for most projects under deployment. So even "development" under windows environments is generally limitted.

Comment: @dvijaz thanks! although i don't know how to change the config for a debugging / running specific file, i tried creating a new project and following same steps, this time explicitly selecting node.exe in config.  Once it's save i can't yet find a way to change it, but it does work for now.

Comment: @NeilLunn the answer really can't be running a linux vm for development using node surely?  what limitations are there?

Comment: as my answer was deleted (thanks to @NeilLunn), I'll try to repeat it here. Surely you don't need running linux to make it work, Just make sure to specify the correct path to your node interpreter ("C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe") in Settings/Languages&Frameworks/Node.js and NPM, and make sure it's not overwritten in your run configuration (Run/Edit Configurations). "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" is not a correct path

Comment: @lena thanks! i kind of sussed it out, although the paths did not seems to be taken into account until i restarted WS.  My question was very aggressively modified, as it seems your answer was.  thanks for help anyway.  I can't accept the only way to develop using node was to ditch Windows OS.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error while [using WebStorm with Babel as the Node executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440811/debug-compiled-es6-nodejs-app-in-webstorm/37723484#37723484). After re-installing the dependencies, the correct path to the babel-node executable was `node_modules\.bin\babel-node.cmd`.

Comment: I came from a linux machine and accidentally used babel-node instead of .cmd one. So if you're on windows make sure it ends with .cmd like Dan said.