# ES6 debugging with Webstorm (Babel)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Have webstorm v10, babel file-watcher working fine and all is good.

Now i want to debug the code, any way to debug the ES6 file itself or must do it on the JS output file babel compiled?

Please advise.

Comment: you can debug your es6 files when using e.g. the chrome developer tools. And you have to enable sourcemaps.

Comment: Basically i'm referring to the NodeJS server files.. till now i debugged it via Webstorm with breakpoints and all.. now looks like i can only debug the generated JS files..

Comment: oh, you want to debug serverside code?! hmm. meybe you can add sourcemaps to the ide?!

Comment: Yes, looks like it's the better option, i have to learn how this sourcemap working on the backend. :) tnx.

Comment: has anyone figure this out for webstorm/babel/node yet?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue concerning this in [Jetbrains' ticket system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29440811/3580261). I think this issue is resolved. 
Also see the corresponding GitHub [issue in the Babel repo.](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/983)

There is an [example setup on Jetbrains' blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/), basically setting up babel flags such us `--source-maps`.

This could be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29440811/3580261).

Comment: this has nothing to do with the webstorm debugger.